# Disable Print Screen Button

Tags: java, screenshot

Can I disable the print screen button, while my application is on? Can we use the print screen button as one of the coded keyboard inputs, and equal it to do nothing?

Comment: so you don't want any body to capture the screen while your application is running?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this without affecting the Operating System settings via registry edits, etc.

A user can always unfocus your application, and press print screen taking a capture of the whole screen otherwise.

Comment: But I can find a way to not allow the user to unfocus, then how??